# how to get value array using key from array

Tags: php, arrays

**What I want to do**

here is the main array

```
   Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 8
                        [title] => test123
                        [description] => test123
                        [year] => 2012
                        [photo] => test123.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 9
                        [title] => here title
                        [description] => here title
                        [year] => 2012
                        [photo] => here.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 11
                        [title] => here title 2
                        [description] => here title 2
                        [year] => 2012
                        [photo] => here.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 12
                        [title] => here title 3
                        [description] => here title 3
                        [year] => 2013
                        [photo] => here.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 13
                        [title] => here title 4
                        [description] => here title 4
                        [year] => 2014
                        [photo] => here.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [Culture] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 14
                        [title] => here title 5
                        [description] => here title 5
                        [year] => 2015
                        [photo] => here.JPG                        
                        [datetime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        [status] => 0
                    )

            )               
    )
```

now from this array I want array of year (by key)
like:

```
Array
(
[0]=>2012
[1]=>2013
[2]=>2014
[3]=>2015
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its working for me

```
    foreach($cultures as $row)
    {
        $year[]=$row['Culture']['year'];
    }
    $year = array_unique($year);
    $year = array_values($year);
    echo "<pre>";print_r($year);
```

Comment: what does using array_values twice achieve? Also, this is the same as the above answers.

Comment: yes Mr D, your code is right and array_values is here for re-index array, but am changing it, thanks for your answer

Answer (score 2):

Loop through your array and assign those years to a new array with their keys intact.

```
$years=array();
foreach($yourArray as $key=>$value)
{
   $years[$key]=$value["Culture"]["year"];
}
$years = array_unique($years);
print_r($years);
```

Comment: +1 for using `$key=>$value` instead of just `$value`

Answer (score 1):

```
$years = [];
foreach($arr as $newarray){
  $years[] = $newarray['Culture']['year'];
}
$years = array_unique($years);
```

The new array years will now hold all the years in the old array. `array_unique` will get rid of all duplicate years.

Answer (score 1):

You can first loop through the array with a `foreach` loop and then use [`array_unique`](http://php.net/array_unique) to get the array of years:

```
$years = array();
foreach ($records as $record) {
    $years[] = $record['Culture']['year'];
}
$years = array_unique($years);
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/53010)

Answer (score 1):

My way is to use [array-walk](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) that takes anonymous function to fill the array, the solution will be in only one line of code.

Comment: but we have to create filter function, so ultimately its the same,anyway thanks and upvoted yr answer